# How do I make an offer redeemable everyday(from midnight to midnight) vs every 24 hours?

Tags: node.js, reactjs, postgresql

I am trying to understand how to modify my 'timeDiff' so that I am able to redeem based on if it is a new day vs whether it has been 24 hours. Any advice?

```
let timeDiff = prevRedemp ? Math.floor((new Date - new Date(prevRedemp.createdAt)) / 1000 / 60 / 60) : undefined;

 // daily use
        } else if (discFreq === 1) {
          if (timeDiff >= 24 || prevRedemp === undefined) {
            return this.models.Redemption.create({
              UserUuid: userUuid,
              DiscountId: discountId,
              BusinessId: disc.dataValues.BusinessId,
              locationId: locationId || null
            }).then(redeemed => {
              return this.models.BusinessRating.findOne({
                where: {
                  UserUuid: userUuid,
                  BusinessId: disc.dataValues.BusinessId
                }
              }).then(rating => {
                if (rating) {
                  return redeemed;
                } else {
                  return this.models.Notification.create({
                    UserUuid: userUuid,
                    notifyDate: moment().format(),
                    notifyType: 'redemption',
                    RedemptionId: redeemed.id
                  }).then(() => redeemed);
                }
              });
            })
          } else {
            return `Discount cannot be redeemed again for ${24 - timeDiff} hours`;
          }
```

Answer (score 0):

It's not entirely clear to me what your end problem is, but you can create a Date object for the next midnight boundary in the current server time zone like this:

```js
let midnt = new Date();
midnt.setHours(24);       // set hours to the next midnight boundary
midnt.setMinutes(0);      // clear minutes, seconds, milliseconds to zero
midnt.setSeconds(0);
midnt.setMilliseconds(0);
console.log(midnt.toString());
```

This gives you a midnight reference that you can calculate time differences from.  For example, if you want something to expire at the next stroke of midnight, you can either set the expiration absolute time for that or if you are working with time differences from now, you can subtract that time in the future from the current time to get the time difference between now and midnight.

If you want the midnight after the next one (so you always get at least 24 hours), then you can just increase the day of the month by one or add `24 * 60 * 60 * 1000` milliseconds to the ordinal value of the midnight date or you can just increase the day of the month by one to move it forward a day.

Comment: This did provide a solution to my question. Thank you.